# Wordpress - Dynamic "static" permalink based on permalink taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks, taxonomy

I'm running an application that has a problem that I'll be glad if anyone help me with it.

Today, my permalink looks like:

http://example.com/%estado%/%category%/%postname%/

(Where %estado% is a custom taxonomy I've created. Already working and stuff)

And I want to:

http://example.com/%estado%/%dynamic%/%category%/%postname%/

In that way...

`if %estado% == 'br'
$dynamic = 'dou'
else
$dynamic = 'doe'`

But I can't figure out how to.

Anyone?

Thanks in advance! :)

(Sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a new taxonomy for the "dynamic" path.